# Learning accents

Tags: spoken-english

What is a good way to learn speaking english with good accent? 
I know english very well, but have a problem with speaking like a native speaker. I have a problem with the letter "r" and can't get over it. How do I learn the proper way to speak "r" in english and sound natural?

Comment: Which accent would you like to use - there really isn't any specific accent that is perfect, other than my own of course!

Comment: American. The problem is, that I can't say the "r" properly with my voice, I have to lower it a lot to get that sound.

Comment: @TymekWojnarowski The American English [r] is difficult for speakers of many languages, so don't feel bad. I suggest watching some YouTube videos which illustrate, using animations, how the tongue is used. As your tongue is not used to moving this way, the muscles and muscle memory are not developed yet - but with practice they will improve a lot. Don't worry and keep trying!

Comment: Not all American accents pronounce 'r' in the way many people think of when they imagine an "American accent". New York for example.

Comment: Yes, but there must be some way for me to sound more like an american and less like a stereotypical russian from movies, even tough I am not from russia.

Answer (score 1):

BBC has usually perfectly British accent speakers, so you can try watching BBC World News.
I use Netflix a lot , and try to watch everything without subtitles or at least with English subtitles.
You will get a lot of examples of different accents, from US and UK.
Then just try to repeat what they say!

Comment: But try to avoid regional accents !

Comment: Speaking like a Scouser is _so cool_. Jodie Comer for example.

Comment: I am watching everything with subtitles and that is how I improved my english a lot. But I've never tried repeating after them, so I will try that, thanks!